# Is asking about mantras on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are more than 10,000 mantras in Hindu religion. and I think there will be more than 10,000 questions in future which are just related to mantras. I know it doesn't matter but some of the users concern about revealing some powerful mantras on internet. They say that it should not be read in a usual manner or in improper way. I respect their concern.

How we can tackle this issue? and shall we keep mantras on-topic? if yes, then up to which extent?

Comment: I am not sure about this as the topic is too broad, lets see what experts has to say ....

Comment: @Mr.Alien it is broad but still a part of Hinduism. if we don't include this post in this site then we can't have it anywhere. but then again, including this topic (_to be precise, some mantras_) might concern pundits who visit here (_not sure_).

Comment: Nah nah, you got me wrong, broad not in the sense of asking question, broad in the sense of nature -> *10,000 mantras in Hindu religion* :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I meant the same :)

Comment: asking about specific mantras is like asking about medicines. While its no harm for commonly known mantras like hare krishna, shanti mantra, etc., certain *agamic* mantras shouldn't be asked about because only real experts know that. It's a completely different department like Ayurveda.  Unless there are real experts, people may give various meanings and faulty mantras which can be harmful. So asking about commonly known mantras should be allowed but questions that ask mantras as solutions or advice should be disallowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to me, asking about **meaning of Mantras** should be considered as off topic, an example for this..

- Meaning of Om Bhur Bhuva Swaha
- Meaning of Tamaso Ma Jyotirgamaya

I could just go on with this, as you stated that we have thousands of mantras, I can post a few hundreds of them ...

---

**So whats on-topic?**

Questions asking the reason behind chanting that mantra, or a similar way should be considered as on-topic for example

- Is the Gayatri mantra used to worship the sun or Goddess Gayatri?
- What is the significance of ॐ (Om/Aum)?

In a way, these questions are really good, they do have mantras as the main topic to discuss on, and hence they will be helpful for future visitors as well, also they are not asking the meaning behind the mantra only, so I think asking about mantras should be on topic, as they are one of the core in Hinduism, but lets keep the meaning questions as off-topic

Comment: What is your opinion on asking mantras as solutions or advice (an issue pointed out by @jabahar in his comment)?

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran off-topic.. it will lead to opinion-based suggestions.

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran I feel that should be off topic, as advice may vary from user to user, so opinion based questions are not fit for the community

Comment: This is a good idea. Mostly, while giving the reason people also provide it's meaning.